# Chart data will not load in ng2-charts/Chart.JS

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to create a simple line chart with ng2-charts.  If I use hard coded data for my data, it works fine.  I'm trying to use a variable which is an array of strings, but when I use the variable instead of hard-coded data, it just doesn't load.  I need to type more so that the post will submit.  I'm not sure what else to say.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

body.component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/data.service';
import { Chart, ChartConfiguration, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.scss'],
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
  city: any;
  lat: any;
  lon: any;
  weatherData: any;
  uv: any;
  airData: any;
  airQual: any;
  graphData: any = {};
  timeData: any = [];
  tempData: any = [];
  xAxisData: any;
  yAxisData: any;
  adjust: number = 0;
  loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public dataSerivce: DataService) {
    Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.loaded, "FIRST")
    console.log(this.tempData, "FIRST")
    this.city = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('city');
    this.lat = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lat');
    this.lon = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lon');
    this.dataSerivce.getData2(this.lat, this.lon).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.weatherData = data;
      }
      if (this.weatherData.daily[0].uvi < 3) {
        this.uv = 'Low';
      } else if (this.weatherData.daily[0].uvi < 6) {
        this.uv = 'Moderate';
      } else if (this.weatherData.daily[0].uvi < 8) {
        this.uv = 'High';
      } else if (this.weatherData.daily[0].uvi > 7) {
        this.uv = 'Very High';
      }
    });
    this.dataSerivce.getAir(this.lat, this.lon).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.airData = data;
      }
      if (this.airData.list[0].main.aqi === 1) {
        this.airQual = 'Good';
      } else if (this.airData.list[0].main.aqi === 2) {
        this.airQual = 'Fair';
      } else if (this.airData.list[0].main.aqi === 3) {
        this.airQual = 'Moderate';
      } else if (this.airData.list[0].main.aqi === 4) {
        this.airQual = 'Poor';
      } else if (this.airData.list[0].main.aqi === 5) {
        this.airQual = 'Very Poor';
      }
    });
    this.dataSerivce.getHourData(this.lat, this.lon).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.graphData = data;
      }
      if (this.graphData.timezone_offset === -14400) {
        this.adjust = -3600;
      } else if (this.graphData.timezone_offset === -25200) {
        this.adjust = 7200;
      } else if (this.graphData.timezone_offset === -21600) {
        this.adjust = 3600;
      } else {
        this.adjust = 0;
      }
      this.tempData = this.graphData.hourly
        .slice(0, 8)
        .map((graph: any) => graph.temp.toFixed());
      this.timeData = this.graphData.hourly
        .slice(0, 8)
        .map((graph: any) =>
          formatDate(graph.dt * 1000, 'h a', 'en-US').toString()
        );
      this.loaded = true;
      console.log(this.loaded, "SECOND")
      console.log(this.tempData, "SECOND")
    });
  }
  public lineChartData: ChartConfiguration['data'] = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Temp',
        data: this.tempData,
        fill: true,
        borderColor: '#f1612b',
        backgroundColor: '#f1642b2e',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 0,
        tension: 0.25,
        datalabels: {
          labels: {
            value: {
              color: 'black',
            },
          },
          align: 'end',
          offset: -0.5,
        },
      },
    ],
    labels: this.timeData
  };

  public lineChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
        },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          display: false,
        },
        grace: 3,
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  };

  public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';
}
```

body.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="loaded == true" style="display: block">
            <canvas
              baseChart
              width="490"
              height="175"
              [data]="lineChartData"
              [options]="lineChartOptions"
              [type]="lineChartType"
            ></canvas>
```

Comment: This looks like a asynchronous issue, you assign tempData inside a subscription but assign the lineChartData variable outside it, which means it will instantiate that variable (lineChartData ) with tempData being an empty array. You probably want to move the assigning of lineChartData to inside of the subscription where you get that data, looks like the getHourData method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your DevTools and check if there are any errors in your console.
2. Do a `console.log(this.tempData)` and `console.log(this.timeData)` and check if these variables have the same data format as your "static" data that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the Chart doesn't notice that the data in the array has changed. You can reinitialize the data and then the chart gets an auto-refresh.

```
this.tempData = {...this.tempData}
```

If you still have the problem it would be nice if you provide the data of the console.log statements.